# Cheetah pre-compiled template usage

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

For performance reason as suggested [here](http://packages.python.org/Cheetah/recipes/precompiled.html), I am studying how to used the pr-compiled template.

I edit `hello.tmpl` in template directory as

```
#attr title = "This is my Template"
<html>
    <head>
        <title>\${title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello \${who}!
    </body>
</html>
```

then issued `cheetah-compile.exe .\hello.tmpl` and get the `hello.py`

In another python file `runner.py`, I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Cheetah.Template import Template
from template import hello
def myMethod():
    tmpl = hello.hello(searchList=[{'who' : 'world'}])
    results = tmpl.respond()
    print tmpl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myMethod()
```

But the outcome is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello ${who}!
    </body>
</html>
```

Debugging for a while, I found that inside `hello.py`:

```
def respond(self, trans=None):



    ## CHEETAH: main method generated for this template
    if (not trans and not self._CHEETAH__isBuffering and not callable(self.transaction)):
        trans = self.transaction # is None unless self.awake() was called
    if not trans:
        trans = DummyTransaction()
```

it looks like the trans is None, so it goes to `DummyTransaction`, what did I miss here? 
Any suggestions to how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that in runner.py inside `myMethod()` instead of

```
print tmpl
```

You need

```
print results
```

Additionally, your code has some formatting problems:

1. don't escape the ${title} with a backslash
2. you need `if __name__ == '__main__':` instead of `if name == 'main':`